# MongoDB field select include documents without field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Lets say I have a collection with two documents in...

```
{"_id": ..., "msg": "hello world"}
{"_id": ..., "name": "bob dylan"}
```

and a query...

```
db.collection.find({}, {"text": 1})
```

Why does this return both documents? Is there a way to return only when the msg field exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query returns both documents because your criteria is empty (`{}`):

```
db.collection.find({}, {"text": 1})
```

If you only want to find documents where the `msg` field exists, you can use [`$exists`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists):

```
db.collection.find({ msg: { $exists: true}}, { "text" : 1 })
```

Note that for the second parameter to `find()`, you are only requesting the value of the `text` field to be displayed.